# How to fix render darken after texturing in blender cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, texturing, light

I'm an 11 year-old who has close to zero experience with blender and was recommended to try it by a friend. I had rendered an image without texture and it was very well lit. But, after I textured it in blender cycles it became very dark.

Before Texturing In Blender Cycles
[image: Before Texturing In Blender Cycles]

After Texturing In Blender Cycles
[image: After Texturing In Blender Cycles]

Comment: It's all about the light. you are using very flat lighting. Please edit your question and and images that show how your lights and world settings are set up

Comment: Your second render has no lamps, it is only illuminated by the flat gray world background.  The first image seems to have a point lamp to the bottom-left.

Comment: Some kind of lights do not work in Cycles, since you are rendering the same scene, I'm guessing you already have a Hemy light, try changing the light type to Sun, Area or Spot.

Comment: Here is a nice tutorial on using lights in Cycles
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UTwXG3K4l2g

Answer (score 1):

An expanded answer of @cegaton and @PCmath.

In cycles lighting can be one of the most important aspects of a render, it can make a dull image into a full vibrant master piece.

Here's a quick render with only three objects: A floor, Suzanne, and finally a camera. I added no lights to this scene.

[image: No lights]

Here's the exact same scene with a light, i used the light "Sun".

[image: With lights]

Without lights the scene can look dull. To add a light press the tab on your bottom left labeled "Add" click expand lights, and select your desired light. Experiment and find out what's best for your scene.

[image: Adding lights]